# How to find the ratio of a length command (e.g., \textwidth) to a reference value (e.g., 6cm) ?

Tags: calculations

How to find the ratio of a length command (e.g., `\textwidth`) to a reference value (e.g., `6cm`) ? Actually I want to use the ratio for the `\scalebox` argument, e.g., `\scalebox{<ratio>}`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{pgf}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}{\the\textwidth/(6cm)}

\makeatletter
  \FPdiv\thecm{6}{2.54} %72.27
  \FPmul\thecminpoints{\thecm}{72.27}
  \FPdiv\thescale{\strip@pt\textwidth}{\thecminpoints}%
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\noindent%
%\scalebox{\thescale}{%
\scalebox{\ratio}{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
\pnode(2,2){A}\psframe(A)
\pnode(4,2){B}\pscircle(B){2}
\end{pspicture}}
\uput[-135](A){$A$}
\rput(B){$B$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Could you just change `\begin{pspicture}(6,4)` to `\begin{pspicture}(\textwidth)` ?

Comment: @Will, you try it first :)

Comment: Oops; I did try it but I got a bit confused with what I was seeing with the output. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: No problem Will, it is fun!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

TeX can do 64-bit integer mul-divs; the resulting integer can be converted to a decimal number via the sp-to-pt conversion:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\textwidth*65536/\number\dimexpr6cm\relax\relax sp\relax
\end{document}
```

Or, more general:

```
\documentclass{minimal}
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DivideLengths}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\dimexpr#1\relax*65536/\number\dimexpr#2\relax\relax sp\relax
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\DivideLengths{\textwidth - 0.2\textheight}{2cm + 4cm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank Philipp, your code scares me. I am not familiar with plain tex. I don't know how to plug it into my problem.

Comment: The `\DivideLengths` macro from the second snipped simply expands to a decimal representation of the ratio.

Comment: Good solution.

Comment: thanks. Could you help me to describe how to parse your macro step by step? I don't know how this macro works. What is the \number, \relax, etc for?

Comment: this is very good formula but passers-by, please note: all three `\number`'s in `\DivideLengths` are superfluous and only slow down processing by `\numexpr` and `\dimexpr`.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `\the\textwidth` to give you the value of the dimension in points and you can use that to calculate the width in cm (in inch (1 in is 72.27 pt)).

You can automate all these with LaTeX calculations depending for what you need the calculations.

**Edit**

I would use the `fp` package for the calculations as follows:

```
\makeatletter
  \FPdiv\thecm{6}{2.54} %72.27
  \FPmul\thecminpoints{\thecm}{72.27}
  \FPdiv\thescale{\strip@pt\textwidth}{\thecminpoints}%
  \thescale
\makeatother

\scalebox{\thescale}{Test}
```

Comment: @xport There might be shorter and more elegant ways to do it, but I would do it this way. Search for LaTeX3 calculations for other ways on this site. There was also question on `strip@pt` that explains how this strips the point.

Comment: Thank again Yiannis. Well done. But \thescale before \makeatother must be removed.

Comment: @xport Sure, I put it there so one can see the result of the calculation, you can just comment it out.

Answer (score 6):

TeX doesn't have a data type for decimal numbers and can't natively divide dimensions (for the mathematicians: TeX's dimensions form a one-dimensional vector space over the field of rational numbers, but not a field by themselves).  You can use `pgfmath` to do it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}
\begin{document}

\pgfmathsetmacro{\ratio}{\the\textwidth/(6cm)}
\scalebox{\ratio}{\fbox{stuff}}

\end{document}
```

But the confused questions and presumptive answers are saying that there might be a better way to get what you really want.

Comment: In fact, TeX dimensions are always integers, which can be multiplied and divided without any external package.

Comment: @Phillipp: I'm confused.  What is the smallest dimension then?

Comment: @Philipp:  You are right! TeXbook, Chapter 10, p. 58 "TeX represents all dimensions as an integer multiple of the tiny units called `sp`" which is 1/65536 of a point.  But you have still have to extract this multiple if you want to divide them, right?

Comment: TeX does the division by 65536 when it has to print the decimal representation of a dimension. So generally you can use integer arithmetic, multiply by 65536 (before division to avoid rounding), have TeX treat the result as a dimension, convert that to the result string, and strip the unit suffix.

Answer (score 2):

I think you probably want

```
\resizebox{0.5\textwidth}{!}{...}
```

Comment: I want \scalebox{\textwidth divided by 6 cm}{stuff}

Comment: @xport What on earth for? I'm up too late so I might have lost it, but this doesn't seem like a rational scaling factor for a box of unknown size.

Comment: @xport Given your latest edit what's wrong with replacing the `\scalebox` line by `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{` ?

Comment: Sorry Will, it does not make sense. :)

Comment: @xport looking at this again for some reason, I have no idea what you mean. You're trying to make the box as wide as the page, right? So why not just tell TeX that's how large you want it (using \resizebox) instead of calculating the scale factor manually?

Answer (score 0):

You can compute expandably (hence as argument to `\scalebox`) using [xintfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xint)

[image: circles]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[showframe=true]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-node}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{xintfrac}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\scalebox{\xintRound {5}{\textwidth/\dimexpr 6cm\relax}}{%
\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
\pnode(2,2){A}\psframe(A)
\pnode(4,2){B}\pscircle(B){2}
\end{pspicture}}
\uput[-135](A){$A$}
\rput(B){$B$}
\end{document}
```

Further remarks:

1. the first argument `5` to  `\xintRound` is the number of digits to keep after the decimal mark for the output; the fraction is computed exactly before this rounding. Presence of a denominator is optional, `\xintRound {4}{1.2345678}` outputs <strike>`1.235`</strike> (oops) `1.2346`.
2. numerator and denominator **involving arithmetic operations with** `+`, `*`, `-` **and parentheses** (which will get executed automatically inside a `\numexpr`) should not have more than eight tokens (here the denominator has already five). For longer input use `\the\numexpr <complicated stuff>\relax` for the numerator or, respectively, the denominator.
3. or, you can also load package `xintexpr` and have input such as `\xintRound {5}{\xinttheexpr arbitrarily complicated expression \relax}`. For example `\xinttheexpr \LenA*\LenB*\LenC/((\LenD+\LenE)*(\LenF+\LenG))\relax` will compute exactly without arithmetic overflow. Use then `\xintRound` to print it as fixed point number with the desired number of digits after decimal mark (if you want truncation rather than rounding, use `\xintTrunc`).

   3a. release `1.1` of `xint` will have the syntax `\xinttheiexpr [4] ... \relax` as a shortcut to `\xintRound {4}{\xinttheexpr ... \relax}`
4. if the same computation has to be performed many times, just do it once in an `\edef`: `\edef\RATIO{\xintRound{5}{<numerator>/<denominator>}}`, and then use `\RATIO` wherever needed.
5. if you want to use explicit dimensions such as `6cm` or `1.2345in` then put it in `\dimexpr .. \relax` and, if you are not using `\xinttheexpr .. \relax` and if these dimension specifications have many digits, you may need to  embed in `\the\numexpr .. \relax` (see point 2 above). Within `\xinttheexpr` just use `\dimexpr 1.2345in\relax`.