# making a big summation sign

Tags: math-mode

How can I make a big summation sign?

```
‎\begin{align}‎
‎\cos x‎ ‎=‎ ‎‎\sum\limits‎_‎{n=0}^{‎\‎‎infty‎} ‎\frac{(ix)^{2n‎}}{(2n)!}‎‎
\end{align}‎
```

this is the code which I'm using for summation

Comment: Isn't that big enough? By the way, you don't need `\limits` in an `align`; and you don't need it elsewhere, either.

Comment: And you don't need `\dfrac` in an `align`, `\frac` is OK.

Comment: I agree with @egreg: using a consistent size of `\sum` could be better than varying the size manually depending on the following expression. Additional fine-tuning can be ok, however I would compare such equation design in good books before.

Comment: thank you very much , that's right but I'm typing my article just in the way my professor asked me !

Answer (score 69, accepted):

You can use the command `\mathlarger` of the [`relsize`](http://ctan.org/pkg/relsize) package. It increases the size and it can be nested. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}‎
‎‎\cos x‎ ‎=‎ \mathlarger{\mathlarger{‎‎\sum}}_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(ix)^2n}{(2n)!}‎‎
\end{equation}‎
\end{document}
```

[image: equation with bigger sum symbol]

.....

Comment: this command cannot be used inside align environment. Is it true ? for me nothing happened when I used this.

Comment: Works fine inside the align.

Comment: @aiag I experience the same problem as Hirak. Using pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.17 (TeX Live 2016/TeX Live for SUSE Linux).

Comment: Just to add to the accepted answer, you should load the `exscale` package in order for `relsize` to scale maths symbols beyond the standard sizes.

Answer (score 36):

Well, there's always a [`graphicx`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/graphicx) solution.

#### `\nsum[<optional>]`

The command `\nsum` resizes the `\sum` symbol by the factor `1.4` (fits OP's fraction). It does take an optional argument to give another factor.

I admit that the `\raisebox` factor calculation is a bit sketchy as it uses the text style `\sum` symbol for the calculation but for `cmr` it's a good fit and I'm too lazy to take a closer look at the needed dimension calculation.

#### `\resum{<arg>}`

Another more dynamic approach would be to take the dimensions of the `\sum`'s terms and resize the `\sum` sign so that it fits their vertical dimensions. To only specify the therms once the `\resum`  also defines (overwrites) `\s` so that one can use

```
\resum{<what to sum>}_{foo}^{bar} \s
```

(I also tried to use `\resizebox` that takes the dimension instead of a factor, but I couldn't quite work out how to use `\resizebox` and `\resizebox*`.)

The second screenshot (produced by the [`lua-visual-debug`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug) package shows why `\resum` is in my eyes unstable and shouldn't be used. (But I don't think that a bigger `\sum` sign is even needed, anyway)

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
%\usepackage{lua-visual-debug} requires LuaTeX (used only for demonstration purposes)
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\depthofsumsign}
\setlength{\depthofsumsign}{\depthof{$\sum$}}
\newlength{\totalheightofsumsign}
\newlength{\heightanddepthofargument}

\newcommand{\nsum}[1][1.4]{% only for \displaystyle
    \mathop{%
        \raisebox
            {-#1\depthofsumsign+1\depthofsumsign}
            {\scalebox
                {#1}
                {$\displaystyle\sum$}%
            }
    }
}
\newcommand{\resum}[1]{%
    \def\s{#1}
    \mathop{
        \mathpalette\resumaux{#1}
    }
}

\newcommand{\resumaux}[2]{% internally
    \sbox0{$#1#2$}
    \sbox1{$#1\sum$}
    \setlength{\heightanddepthofargument}{\wd0+\dp0}
    \setlength{\totalheightofsumsign}{\wd1+\dp1}
    \def\quot{\DivideLengths{\heightanddepthofargument}{\totalheightofsumsign}}
    \nsum[\quot]%
}

% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6424/16595
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DivideLengths}[2]{%
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\dimexpr#1\relax*65536/\number\dimexpr#2\relax\relax sp\relax
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
  \cos x = \nsum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(ix)^2n}{(2n)!}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
  \rlap{\rule[.57ex]{.55\linewidth}{.1pt}}\rlap{\rule{.55\linewidth}{.1pt}}
  \sum_{n=1}^\infty \nsum_{1.4} \nsum[2]_2 \nsum[2.5]_{2.5} \nsum[3]_{n=1}^\infty \nsum[3]_{\displaystyle n=1}^{\displaystyle \infty}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
     \cos x = \resum{\frac{(ix)^2n}{(2n)!}}_{n=0}^\infty \s \quad \resum{\frac{1}{2}}_{n=0}^\infty\s \quad \resum{\frac{\strut 1}{\strut 2}}_{n=0}^\infty\s 
\end{equation}‎
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Main output]

#### A closer look at how `\resum` does (not) work

[image: a closer look]

Answer (score 13):

If you're willing to use the [Mathtime Professional II](http://www.pctex.com/mtpro2.html) font package, you could use its `\xl\sum`, `\XL\sum`, `\XXL\sum` etc commands to get larger summation symbols.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[lite]{mtpro2}
\begin{document}
The summation symbols below are generated by \texttt{\string\sum} as well as by \texttt{\string\xl\string\sum}, \texttt{\string\XL\string\sum}, and  \texttt{\string\XXL\string\sum} of the \texttt{mtpro2} package. (There is also \texttt{\string\XXXL\string\sum}, but it's not shown here.)
\[
     \sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^{-i}} \qquad 
  \xl\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^{-i}} \qquad 
  \XL\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^{-i}} \qquad 
 \XXL\sum_{i=1}^N \frac{1}{2^{-i}}
\]
\end{document}
```

Two additional comments. (i) The `mtpro2` font package isn't free of charge, although it's not exactly expensive either; actually, all that's needed to produce the large summation symbols is the `lite` subset of the package, which *is* free of charge. (ii) The `mtpro2` math font package uses a "Times Roman" font style; this may or may not be to your liking.