# Displayed math looks bad using beamerposter with lmodern

Tags: beamer, fonts, beamerposter, latin-modern

I'm using a theme for `beamerposter` that requires the package `lmodern`.  Specifically, I'm modifying the theme found 
[here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/jacobs-landscape-poster).  However, the displayed equations do not look right when I use `lmodern`.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
  \usepackage{lmodern}
  \usepackage[english]{babel}
  \usepackage{times}\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
  \usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4,debug]{beamerposter}   
  \begin{document}
  \begin{frame}{} 
    \begin{block}
      \centering
      {\VERYHuge $\sum_k^\infty$}
    \end{block}

  \end{frame}
  \end{document}
```

The sigma for the `\sum` here is tiny.  It looks normal if I do not use the line `\usepackage{lmodern}`.  It also works fine if I use `lmodern` in `beamer` without `beamerposter`.

Comment: I had this very problem (my poster didn't use the package "lmodern," but it did use the theme "confposter" which seemed to mess up the scaling.) The "exscale" thing didn't work for me; the only solution I found was to use "graphicx", as described by Qrrbrbirlbel in this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/making-a-big-summation-sign This worked perfectly for me :D

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is the normal (in the sense of systematic) effect on large mathematical symbols when using `lmodern`. You should try with `\usepackage{exscale}` after `lmodern`.

Answer (score 2):

Interesting. May I suggest you may want a package that supports math typesetting, like `mathptmx`, instead of `times`, which does not?

Comment: I'd rather suggest `\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}` or the MathTime Pro Lite (requires non standard installation).