# Small \sum character using beamerposter and lmodern

Tags: equations, beamerposter

I'm using the beamerposter package but I have a problem with one equation:

```
\begin{equation}
    P_\tau = pm_0 + \sum_{x=1}^{X} mr_{\tau,Lx} \cdot pm_{Lx}
\end{equation}
```

which appears like that:

[image: resulting equation]

The problem is obviously the size of the `\sum`.

The package include:

```
\usepackage[orientation=portrait,size=a0,scale=1.4]{beamerposter}
```

Please tell me if you need more information.

Edit: This problem appears when using `\RequirePackage{lmodern}` but without it, my fonts are ugly.

Comment: Please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://www.minimalbeispiel.de/mini-en.html) that showcases your problem. You can delete any other code for this.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! A minimal example is really needed; however you can try loading `\usepackage{exscale}` or `\usepackage{amsmath}` (which is recommended anyway when math typesetting is involved).

Comment: @egreg, thank you but it did not solved the issue. For both: I agree, I'll try to do it, I might even find the origin of the bug doing it... It apparently comes from the template which is not mine...

Comment: This question and its answers may help: "[making a big summation sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/making-a-big-summation-sign)"

Comment: Apparently, the problem is related to this ligne :  `\RequirePackage{lmodern}`

Comment: @Maxime Now it is clear. See this discussion: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/119660/27635

Comment: @karlkoeller perfect. My question is then a duplicate. Thanks a lot. Problem solved.