# sum symbol in tikzposter too small

Tags: amsmath, tikzposter

I am using the tikzposter package and am fairly happy with it except for one small thing: When I have an equation with a sum the sum becomes ridiculously small.

[image: small sum symbol]

I have read the questions about [displaystyle vs textstyle](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/32824/show-inline-math-as-if-it-were-display-math) and am using amsmath. Putting `\displaystyle` in front of `\sum` doesn't change anything.

Does anyone have any idea how to get a "normal" sum symbol?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\title{lalala}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{test}{
  \begin{equation*}
    \Psi = \displaystyle\sum^{n_{max}}_{n=1}C_n
  \end{equation*}
}


\end{document}
```

Comment: it seems to me that the font `cmex` has not been made available at properly large sizes.  as i am not a user of `tikzposter`, and it's not installed on the system i work on, i can't test.  but you might try adding `\usepackage{exscale}` which expands upward the range of sizes in which this font is available.

Comment: Also, [don't use `eqnarray`](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196/eqnarray-vs-align). For a single equation such as that, use `equation*`.

Comment: `\usepackage{exscale}` doesn't help, but after some digging around I found out that removing `\usepackage{lmodern}` does.

Comment: [related](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119660/displayed-math-looks-bad-using-beamerposter-with-lmodern)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's a known bug of the Latin Modern fonts, which only supply the `lmex` font (extensible symbols) at a fixed size.

Note that this affects all “large symbols”, such as `\sum`, `\int`, `\prod` and so on, including extensible braces.

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

% declare `cmex` to be arbitrary scalable
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}

\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\title{lalala}

\begin{document}
\maketitle

\block{test}{
  \[
    \Psi = \sum^{n_{max}}_{n=1}C_n
  \]
}
\block{again}{
  \Huge
  \[
    \Psi = \sum^{n_{max}}_{n=1}C_n
  \]
}
\end{document}
```

**Never** use `eqnarray`.

[image]

Comment: Instead of the code from lines 9 to 18 inclusive, it's simpler to do `\usepackage{fixcmex}`

Answer (score 1):

The how about doing something like scaling the symbol and shifting it a bit to look nice. I know this is not a good practice, but for a poster it should do:

```
\documentclass[25pt, a0paper, portrait]{tikzposter}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} 
\usepackage{lmodern} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\title{lalala}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\block{test}{
  \begin{eqnarray*}
    \Psi = \displaystyle\raisebox{-10pt}{\scalebox{3.2}{\ensuremath{\sum}}}^{n_{max}}_{n=1}C_n
  \end{eqnarray*}
}
\end{document}
```

Remarks:

1. `\scalebox{x}{y}` scales the content `y` by factor `x`. It leaves math mode, so you need to enter it again.
2. `\ensuremath{xx}` enters math mode, either from normal text or from within math mode, i.e., you can always use `\ensuremath`, regardless whether in- or outside of math mode. (You cannot do that `$`). I used it here because initially, I forgot whether `\scalebox` would leave math mode or not.
3. `\raisebox{x}{y}` moves the contents of `y` up by `x`. In the poster, due to `\scalebox`, the sum symbol looked as if it was a bit too high in the formula, so I take it down by raising it a negative amount.