# Problems using lmodern with very small font sizes

Tags: fonts, fontsize

Due to page restriction from my university I had to optimize my formulary sheet by writing more compact. Therefore I switched from the default `Computer Modern Roman` font to `Latin Modern` but now I get a problem with Integrals, Sums, etc. For example the integral got pretty big which is for my taste pretty ugly. (Additionally I used `lmodern` because I wanted to get rid of the over proportional super- and subscripts when I use `fontsize = 6pt`)

Can somebody please explain to me why `lmodern` increases the size of integrals "by default" and give me a decent solution in solving this problem to get the old size back for integrals, sums, ...

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{4}{4}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        W_{12} = \int\limits_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = T_2 - T_1
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Furthermore I added two pictures, one with the default font and the other one with `lmodern` showing the problem exemplary.

[image: Computer Modern Roman]
[image: Latin Modern]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It's a problem with `lmodern` defining the math extension font at a fixed size. See [sum symbol in tikzposter too small](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252354/sum-symbol-in-tikzposter-too-small) for the opposite problem.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=6pt]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% declare `cmex` to be arbitrary scalable
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}


\DeclareMathSizes{6}{6}{4}{4}

\begin{document}

    \begin{equation}
        W_{12} = \int\limits_\gamma \mathbf{F} \cdot d\mathbf{r} = T_2 - T_1
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic. Thanks for the quick reply egreg.