# Changing Math-Font-Size with DeclareMathSizes

Tags: math-mode, fontsize

I am thrilled that [`\DeclareMathSizes`](http://www.slac.stanford.edu/comp/unix/package/tex/latex/fntguide/node19.html) gives such nuanced control over the sizes of the different parts of the equations.  Experimenting with the `mt-size`, `s-size` and `ss-size` paramters.

[image]

Here's another one with change of paramters:

[image]

At this point I noticed that `\Sigma` and `\Pi` always remain the same size.  How can they also be changed?

---

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
%Gummi|065|=)
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\DeclareMathSizes{20}{20}{25}{10}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{qag}\selectfont \fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont

\noindent modular properties of $\theta = \sum q^{n^2}$ and  
$\eta =  q^{1/24} \prod (1 - q^n)$

\end{document}
```

---

How can I control the size of my summation and product operators Σ and Π ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems:

1. TeX Gyre Adventor has a bigger x-height than Computer Modern
2. `lmodern` loads the math extension font at a fixed size

The second problem is the same as described in [Problems using lmodern with very small font sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282917/problems-using-lmodern-with-very-small-font-sizes). Just removing `lmodern` will solve it as well.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage[landscape, margin=0.5in]{geometry}

\DeclareMathSizes{20}{25}{21}{17}

\begin{document}

\fontfamily{qag}\fontsize{20}{30}\selectfont

\noindent modular properties of $\theta = \sum q^{n^2}$ and
$\eta =  q^{1/24} \prod (1 - q^n)$

\end{document}
```

[image]