# Adjust gap between \widehat and letter beneath (in subscripts)

Tags: fonts, symbols, accents, subscripts

I would like to know how to adjust the gap between a widehat and the letter beneath. Here is a minimal working example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\[
E_{\hat{\lambda}}(\lambda) D_{\hat{\lambda}}(\lambda)F_{\hat{\lambda}}(\lambda)
\]
\[
E_{\widehat{\lambda}}(\lambda)D_{\widehat{\lambda}}(\lambda)F_{\widehat{\lambda}}(\lambda)
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: Neither \hat nor \widehat provide a satisfying solution]

The \hat's in the first line are too small to be properly distinguishable. On the contrary, the \widehat's in the second line are too big and do not seem to belong to \lambda anymore because of the big gap between them.

Any idea to make this formula look better ?
In particular, I need to reduce the gap between the \widehat's and the \lambda.
In addition, I would like the size of the hats to be somewhere between the size of \hat's and of \widehat's.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Welcome! You'll see a big improvement as soon as you add `\usepackage{amsmath}`.

Comment: Thank you, indeed adding \usepackage{amsmath} in the MWE fixed the problem there. 
But actually, in my true document I had already \usepackage{amsmath}. The problem was fixed after removing \usepackage{lmodern}.
Are somehow amsmath and lmodern competing against eachother ?
Is it not possible to keep both and still have no issues with widehat ?

Comment: Those details should have been in the question. For the issue with `lmodern`, check [Strange behaviour of `\widetilde` in integrals](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/341308/)

Comment: Thanks a lot !
I'll add the usepackages related to font in the MWE next time ;)

Comment: Also related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/100574/really-wide-hat-symbol and http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63545/big-tilde-in-math-mode