# How to put small \bigvee glyph as a subscript?

Tags: math-mode

I would like to use the infinite join (supremum) operator as a subscript in a math paper. However, for example `$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$` produces the normal size operator in the subscript (see attached picture, on the left), while `$\mathscr{F}_{\vee_{i\in I}x_i}$` looks pretty ugly to my taste (see the picture, on the right).

Could you please help me to put the operator in the subscript in proper size and esthetic shape? I wasn't able to find a solution but I have seen elegant subscript supremum operators used in mathematical texts.

[image]

EDIT: Below is the example of what I have in mind:

[image]

Comment: My mistake in the question (corrected). The right-hand side example uses \vee, which I do not like - it doesn't look good.

Comment: Oh, I see, well then you will probably need to be more specific about what it is you want, what do the elegant subscript supremum operators that you've seen used in mathematical texts look like?

Comment: Maybe this?  `$\mathscr{F}_{{\displaystyle\vee}_{i\in I}x_i}$`

Comment: @Au101 I have added the picture with an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't load `amsmath`, the large symbol font is at a fixed size. It is also when `\usepackage{lmodern}` is used. I show the fix.

## Without `amsmath` (bad)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `amsmath` (good)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `lmodern` (bad again)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

### With `lmodern` and a trick (good)

See [Problems using lmodern with very small font sizes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/282917/problems-using-lmodern-with-very-small-font-sizes)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{lmodern}

% declare `cmex` to be arbitrary scalable
\DeclareFontShape{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}{
  <-7.5> cmex7
  <7.5-8.5> cmex8
  <8.5-9.5> cmex9
  <9.5-> cmex10
}{}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{normal}{OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{largesymbols}{bold}  {OMX}{cmex}{m}{n}

\begin{document}

$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have used the solution without lmodern but with the trick and it works fine. It didn't work without lmodern and without a trick, but I am using some package imposed by a publisher, so it may have been due to its internal settings. Anyway, now it looks as I expected - small and elegant :). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Run with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. For `pdflatex` use `\usepackage{tgtermes}`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Termes Math}
\begin{document}

$\mathscr{F}_{\bigvee_{i\in I}x_i}$
$\mathscr{F}_{\mkern-5mu\vee_{i\in I}x_i}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Looks good, but I find egreg's solution aesthetically more appealing :).