# Problem with integrals in sciposter

Tags: sciposter

I am doing a mathematical poster using the `\documentclass{sciposter}`.

In all of my equations where there are integrals, they appear very small in the poster. My code is the usual

```
\begin{equation}

.... \int_M .....
\end{equation}
```

for example. Is this normal ? How can I modify this to have "normal" integrals ?

Here is the exact code I am using:

```
\begin{equation*}
m_H(N) = \frac{1}{64 \pi^{3/2}}|N|^{1/2} \left( 16 \pi -  \int_{N} H^2 \right),
\end{equation*}
```

In a normal .tex, this compiles just fine, but now that I am using `\documentclass[portrait,a0]{sciposter}`, the integrals are smaller than what follows for example.

Comment: The size of math looks normal relative to that of text.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It looks normal here, can you turn your snippet into a complete example, so that we can copy-paste and compile it directly?

Comment: Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252354/sum-symbol-in-tikzposter-too-small help?

Answer (score 1):

I just read a similar question on another website and everything turned out perfectly fine if one adds the `\usepackage{exscale}` which makes everything at the right scale!