# Why aren't my mathematical operators showing up?

Tags: packages, math-operators

I've inherited a fairly substantial LaTeX document as part of a new job. Unfortunately, I haven't really had time to get to grips with it and it now need to be compiled.

There are no errors (other than some biblatex warnings) but none of the mathematical operators are showing up (=, +, -, > etc.) except for `\times`. I've done some research and have come to the conclusion it's probably a conflict in the packages being used but I can't seem to figure out which one.

The preamble is:

```
\RequirePackage{xcolor}         % Extended colorsx  

\documentclass{BYUTextbookUCTAS}
\usepackage{natbib}
\usepackage[immediate,save]{silence}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern} %definitely need this
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage[tikz]{bclogo}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{lifecon}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{arydshln}

% Sub appendices
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
```

Edit:
Thanks to egreg, I've managed to get the mathematical operators back but now there are some other formatting problems.

I've uploaded a PDF [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wL_6qttt12HoTifUU-1RXUBhj7cci6Pz/view?usp=sharing) showing what happens when I include/exclude the "lmodern" package.

And I've uploaded the cls file [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gmeVsr5fIfoVFmqEXXw0CoETTZjyn3Uz/view?usp=sharing) (pastebin [here](https://pastebin.com/56nbG27h)).

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Without a pointer to the document class it's not possible to help. My crystal ball seems to suggest that `\usepackage{lmodern}` is the culprit.

Comment: Forgive my ignorance (I'm new-ish to LaTeX) but isn't the document class `BYUTextbookUCTAS`? And I also thought it might be `\usepackage{lmodern}` but everything fell apart when I removed that.

Comment: The document class is certainly `BYUTextbookUCTAS`, but it's not generally available and a Google search didn't help.

Comment: Ah, I see! You were right about `\usepackage{lmodern}` - when I remove it, the operators return. Except then all the alignment is out etc. Is this to do with the document class?

Comment: Please, point to a place where the class can be downloaded from and improve your example showing how “the alignment is out”.

Comment: @egreg Sorry about that. I've edited my question.

Comment: your class has `\usepackage{fourier}` so all math characters get redefined to the non standard encoding sused by those fonts so if you switch back to latin modern then the math is broken.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/392667/incompatibility-of-lmodern-and-fourier

Comment: Sorry, but this is still unanswerable, apart from the advice on how to make your symbols to reappear. The `lifecon` package is not available and nobody but you can tell how to show the blue bars. Please, open a new question with the details.