# How to make tikzposter work with lmodern font?

Tags: tikzposter

I have problems making tikzposter work with `lmodern` font.
The resulting document is  using textsyle for sums and integrals.
This does not happen, when using another class like `article` or when removing `lmodern`.

```
\documentclass{tikzposter}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\block{Test}{
\begin{equation}
    \sum_{i=0}^{n}{abc}
\end{equation}
    }
\end{document}
```

```
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for 

some parts that might be related from the log:

OT1+lmr on input line 4.
(/net/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/ot1lmr.fd
File: ot1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OML+lmm on input line 4.
 (/net/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omllmm.fd
File: omllmm.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMS+lmsy on input line 4.
 (/net/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omslmsy.fd
File: omslmsy.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for OMX+lmex on input line 4.
 (/net/TeXLive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/lm/omxlmex.fd
File: omxlmex.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
)
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <17.28> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <12> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <10> on input line 4.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <24.88> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <20.74> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <14.4> on input line 9.
LaTeX Font Info:    External font `lmex10' loaded for size
(Font)              <29.86> on input line 9.
 [1
```

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/261188/586