# small integral symbol in poster

Tags: symbols, beamerposter

I am working on a poster in Latex. I found that the integral sign (and also the summation sign) appears to be small. What could make this happen? I never see this in a regular article. I guess it must have something to do with the poster template.
I'm using this template:
https://www.overleaf.com/latex/examples/quadratic-function/hjbvztxdrvwf#.WRUGqtIrLIU

[image]

Comment: [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/252354/sum-symbol-in-tikzposter-too-small) could be related? Also [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119660/displayed-math-looks-bad-using-beamerposter-with-lmodern?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the fontsize you (or your template) are using is rather big and does not contain an integral symbol of this size. To fix this, you can use the `exscale` package or another font that does contain the symbol in the required size.

```
\documentclass[final]{beamer}
\usepackage[scale=1.24]{beamerposter} 
\usetheme{confposter} 
\usepackage{booktabs} 
\author{matematika.pl} 
\institute{2015} 

\usepackage{exscale}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]

\begin{equation}
    H(f)(x) = \int f(x-t) \frac{dt}{t}
\end{equation}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]