# How to typeset this integral?

Tags: math-mode

I want to typeset the integral

```
$$ \int{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\left(5 - \dfrac{3x}{4}\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
```

I tried

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
$$ \int{\dfrac{1}{\cos^2\left(5 - \dfrac{3x}{4}\right)}}\,\mathrm{d}x$$
\end{document}
```

and I get

[image]

The integration symbol not high enough. How to typeset this integral?

Comment: The `\int` glyph is not scalable. And it shouldn’t be scaled really. But for what it’s worth: [making a big summation sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22773)

Comment: Never use `$$` in LaTeX.

Comment: For more on creating large *integral* symbols, see [Big integral sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39181/5001). However, in the present context I would definitely not advocate inserting a large integral symbol -- it's much better here to use `\frac` (twice) instead of `\dfrac`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Option 1

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\[
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2\left(5 - \frac{3x}{4}\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 2

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\[
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2\left(5 - \frac{3}{4}x\right)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 3

Prof. Enrico likes this style I think.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\[
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2(5 - 3x/4)}\,\mathrm{d}x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option 4

By Thorsten Donig's comment below.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath,xfrac}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\[
\int \frac{1}{\cos^2 (5 - \sfrac{3x}{4})}\,\mathrm{d}x
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Option ∞

Based on Qrrbrbirlbel's and Egreg's comments below.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath,xfrac}

\begin{document}
\abovedisplayskip=0pt\relax% remove this line in  your production
\begin{gather*}
\int \sec^2\left(5 - \tfrac{3x}{4}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\int \sec^2\left(5 - \tfrac 3 4 x\right)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\int \sec^2(5 - 3x/4)\,\mathrm{d}x \\
\int \sec^2\left(5 - \sfrac{3x}{4}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x 
\end{gather*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Personally, I prefer the 2nd option. By the way, is `\left`/`\right` really needed here?

Comment: The space between cos and opening parenthesis looks too big in versions 1 and 2 (due to the use of `\left` and `\right` I think)...

Comment: Mathematically, `\cos^{-2}` is also possible, avoiding the fraction altogether.

Comment: A fourth option would be to typeset the fraction by `\sfrac` from »[xfrac](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac)«.

Comment: Either (1) or (3). Option (4) is out of the question, because this is not about cooking. I'd prefer an italic “d”, but this is another matter. Maybe (1) with `\frac{3}{4}x`. I see you've changed (2) in the meantime: what are `\left` and `\right` doing? Nothing at all apart from adding an unwanted spacing.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel Unfortunately there's somebody who writes `\cos^{-1}` to mean the arccosine, so `\cos^{-2}` would be difficult to interpret.

Comment: Option ∞.2 is the best, followed by Option 2.
Also, the best typeset wouldn't have so many redundant `{` `}` 's.

Comment: @egreg True. Although, I have never seen it outside of my CASIO calculator and `calc.exe`.

Comment: Quite frankly, interpreting `\cos^{-1} x` as `\arccos x` is mathematically pretty reasonable, while `\cos^2 x ≡ (\cos x)^2` is more of an ad-hoc hack just to make this often-occuring expression more concise. But mixing both writings would be _really_ confusing; `\cos^{-2}x` could be interpreted as either `\arccos(\arccos x)` or `(\arccos x)^2` or `1/(\cos x)^2` or even `\arcos x / {\cos x}`, all of which have different results.