# Adjusting the summation sign:

Tags: errors, equations, positioning, vertical-alignment

I would like the limits to be vertically above and below the summation sign. I also need a larger summation sign... This is currently what I have:

```
$x^2sin(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne \pm 1}^\infty \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2} $
```

Any help appreciated!

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Please ask only one question per posting. The first question is a possible duplicate of [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001). The second question is a possible duplicate of [making a big summation sign](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22773/5001).

Answer (score 1):

One of this solutions should be suitable for you. Observe that `\dfrac` requires, e.g., `amsmath`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
%$x^2sin(x) = \sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne \pm 1}^\infty \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2} $

$x^2\sin(x) = \displaystyle\sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne \pm 1}^\infty \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2} $

or

\[
x^2\sin(x) =\sum_{n=-\infty\atop n\ne \pm 1}^\infty \dfrac {4i(-1)^{n}n}{(n^2 - 1)^2}
 \]

\end{document}
```

[image]