# Adjusting the Size of Summation Symbol inside an Enumerate Environment

Tags: math-mode, symbols, enumerate, multicol, size

**Situation**: I am making a compilation of problems involving the summation symbol.

**Problem**: I want to resize my summation symbols but unable to do inside the enumerate environment even with the `relsize` package.

**Question**: Is there an alternative way to resize (i.e enlarge) the summation symbols? Also, does this apply to other math symbols (e.g., integrals)? Thank you.

**EDIT**: I forgot to mention that I already included the

> \everymath{\displaystyle}

to my document. However, I would like to enlarge further the summation symbols beyond what \displaystyle could offer. Is there any way to do this? Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

***Code*** :

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,footskip=0in,paperheight=11in,paperwidth=8.5in,left=1in,right=0.5in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.5in,]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, amsxtra, fancyhdr}
\usepackage{graphicx, parskip, xcolor, url, enumerate}
\usepackage{amsbsy, amstext, amsthm, relsize}


%Commands
\newcommand\sumone{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}}
\newcommand\sumzero{\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}}
\newcommand\sumtwo{\sum\limits_{n=2}^{+\infty}}


 \begin{document}
 Determine whether the following given items are absolutely convergent, conditionally convergent or divergent.

 \setlength\columnsep{-1.3cm}

   \begin{multicols}{4}
   \begin{enumerate}[a.]

   \item $\sumzero \cfrac{2n - 1}{n+3}$
   \item $\sumone \frac{\raisebox{0.15ex}{$6n^2 - 9n + 4$}}{n^3}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{3n - 2n^2}{n^2+1}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{2 + \sin n}{4+n^2}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{2n}{n^{3/2} +2}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+n^2}}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{n}{n+1}$
   \item $\sumone \dfrac{n + \sqrt{n}}{n^3 + 1}$
   \item $\sumtwo \dfrac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln n}}$
   \item $\sumone \left(\dfrac{2}{n\sqrt{n}} + \left( \dfrac{-4}{3} \right)^n\right)$

   \end{multicols}
   \end{enumerate}
   \end{document}
```

Comment: Have you seen the posting [Show inline math as if it were display math](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/32824/5001)? Prefix `\displaystyle` before `\sum` (or `\sumzero`, `\sumone`), `\int`, etc.

Comment: There's `tasks` package for this purpose.

Comment: relevant answer: [make summation sign big without affecting the size of lower bound of summation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/200661/579)  it includes some good advice.

Answer (score 3):

By "resizing" the summation symbols, I assume you want to *enlarge* them, so that they have the size used in display-math environments. This may be achieve most directly by placing `\displaystyle` directives ahead of `\sum` macros that occur in inline-math environment.

This works for `\int`, `\prod`, and other so-called variable-sized operator symbols as well.

Having to remember to type `\displaystyle` at the start of lots of inline math groups is tedious. To make *all* inline-math instances behave according to `\displaystyle`, provide the instruction `\everymath{\displaystyle}` at the start of the environment of interest -- here: an `enumerate` environment.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[includeheadfoot,footskip=0in,letterpaper,
            left=1in,right=0.5in,top=0.7in,bottom=0.5in,
           ]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath, enumerate, multicol}

%Commands
\newcommand\sumone{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}}
\newcommand\sumzero{\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}}
\newcommand\sumtwo{\sum_{n=2}^{\infty}}

\begin{document}
Determine whether the following given items are absolutely convergent, 
conditionally convergent, or divergent.

\setlength\columnsep{-1cm}

\begin{multicols}{4}
\begin{enumerate}[a.]
\everymath{\displaystyle}  % <-- new!
\item $\sumzero\frac{2n - 1}{n+3}$  % I wouldn't use "\cfrac"
\item $\sumone \frac{6n^2 - 9n + 4}{n^3}$ % I removed the "\raisebox" wrapper
\item $\sumone \frac{3n - 2n^2}{n^2+1}$
\item $\sumone \frac{2 + \sin n}{4+n^2}$
\item $\sumone \frac{2n}{n^{3/2} +2}$
\item $\sumone \frac{(-1)^n}{\sqrt{n+n^2}}$
\item $\sumone \frac{n}{n+1}$
\item $\sumone \frac{n + \sqrt{n}}{n^3 + 1}$
\item $\sumtwo \frac{1}{n\sqrt{\ln n}}$
\item $\sumone \left(\frac{2}{n\sqrt{n}} + 
               \left(\frac{-4}{3}\right)^{\!\!n}\,\right)$

\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Comment: However, what  if I want to enlarge further the summation symbols, say as big as the ``fraction" itself? Is there a way to do this?

Comment: @Enthusiast - Sure: use `\mathlarger` (provided by the `\relsize` package).

Comment: However,  the package seems to only  enlarge the upper and the lower limit of my document and not the summation symbol itself :(

Comment: @Enthusiast - What do you mean? `\mathlarger{\sum}` is clearly larger than `\sum`.

Comment: I think there is something wrong with my code:

Comment: Is this code correct: \newcommand\sumone{\mathlarger\mathlarger{\sum\limits_{n=1}^{+\infty}}}}

Comment: @Enthusiast - No it's not. I would break up the code into two parts. First, `\newcommand{\bigsum}{\mathlarger{\mathlarger{\sum}}}`. Second, `\newcommand{\sumone}{\bigsum_{n=1}^{\infty}}`. As you're going to use these symbols only if `\displaystyle` in effect, you can safely omit the `\limits` directives.

Comment: I did not mean to click but thanks for your help. :)

Comment: I think `\everymath{\displaystyle\everymath{}}` is safer, but it's just nitpicking. By the way, you could mention `tasks` package ;)