# Summation Symbol

Tags: math-mode

Want to write a summation symbol in the similar form in the attachment. Please advice.

[image]

Comment: Um, `\sum_k^n \begin{matrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}` if you're using amsmath.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\newlength{\depthofsumsign}
\setlength{\depthofsumsign}{\depthof{$\sum$}}
\newlength{\totalheightofsumsign}
\newlength{\heightanddepthofargument}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22773/making-a-big-summation-sign
\newcommand{\nsum}[1][1.4]{
  \mathop{%
    \raisebox
    {-#1\depthofsumsign+1\depthofsumsign}
    {\scalebox
      {#1}
      {$\displaystyle\sum$}%
    }
  }
}

\begin{document}

\[
\sum_k^n \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \nsum[2]_k^n \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

Here are two further solutions:

- Instead of enlarging the summation symbol, shrink the matrix, by using a `psmallmatrix` environment instead of a `pmatrix` environment.
- Load the `relsize` package and employ `\larger` instructions to enlarge the size of the `\sum` symbol. In the code below, I create a macro called `\bigsum`. By default, the applies `\larger` three times, for a total magnification of `(1.2)^3=1.728`. (Doubling the `\sum` symbols seems excessive to me...)

The following code also re-implements the `\nsum` macro shown in [@caverac's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/429782/5001), so that TeX does all the hard work, mainly via a `\vcenter` instruction. This seems nicer than performing several length calculations and then employing a `\raisebox` instruction.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools} % for 'pmatrix' environment
\usepackage{relsize}   % for '\larger' macro
\usepackage{graphicx}  % for '\scalebox' macro

\newcommand\nums{0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0} % handy shortcut macro

% default enlargement applied by `\bigsum`: 3 steps of 1.2 
\newcommand\bigsum[1][3]{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{%
   \larger[#1]{$\displaystyle\sum$}}}}}

% reimplementation of '\nsum': make TeX do all the hard work
\newcommand{\nsum}[1][1.44]{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{%   % 1.44=(1.2)^2
   \scalebox{#1}{$\displaystyle\sum$}}}}}

\begin{document}
\[
  \sum_k^n    \begin{psmallmatrix} \nums \end{psmallmatrix}
= \sum_k^n         \begin{pmatrix} \nums \end{pmatrix}
= \bigsum_k^n      \begin{pmatrix} \nums \end{pmatrix}
= \nsum[1.728]_k^n \begin{pmatrix} \nums \end{pmatrix}  % 1.728=(1.2)^3
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: This answer is better! `\bigsum`!

Comment: @Kuttens -- Thanks! :-) What I like about the `\bigsum` approach, as opposed to the `nsum` approach, is that it gives an explicit nod to the typographic principle that when scaling objects and symbols, it's rarely a good idea to use arbitrary scaling factors. Given that many TeX fonts are organized around geometric progressions with a scaling factor of 1.2, it's usually a good starting point to choose powers of 1.2 as well.

Comment: @Mico I'm interested to the organization of fonts around the geometric progressions with a scaling factor of two. I never heard of this thing. Have you perhaps some reference?

Comment: @giusva - In LaTeX, if the document font size is 10pt, `\large` is 20% larger than `\normalsize`, `\Large` is 20% larger than `\large`, `\LARGE` is 20% larger than `\Large`, etc. The 20% steps are not unique to LaTeX. Why 20% and not, say, 15% or 25%? I've never found an explicit reference on this topic; however, I suspect that 20% came about in part because 1.2 is quite close to the 4th root of 2. (`1.189^4=2`) Since the factor `2` has special significance in many parts of Western culture, incl. music, I think it's not surprising that some typographers chose 1.2 as a basic scaling factor.

Comment: @giusva - Oddly, when it comes to math typesetting and the choice of scaling factors for subscript- and subsubscript-mode material, a widely used scaling factor (incl. in TeX) is `0.7`, not `1/1.2=0.833`: `\scriptsize` corresponds to `0.7*\normalsize`,  and `\scriptscriptstyle` (text-mode equivalent: `\tiny`) is `0.5\normalsize`: `0.7*0.7=0.49\approx 0.5`. I have no idea if Knuth himself has ever written about how he came up with the `1.2` factor for upscaling in text mode and the `0.7` factor for downscaling in math mode.

Comment: If you are intersted in this topic, I've asked a [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/429831/why-is-large-is-20-bigger-than-large-large-is-20-bigger-than-large-etc) with this purpouse in mind.

Answer (score 1):

In `unicode-math`, you can load another copy of a math font with the `scale=` parameter to increase the size of a math symbol.  This would be wrapped in several different macros to insert the glyph from text mode and treat it as a math operator with limits above and below.  Based on suggestions in the comments, this also centers the symbol vertically and sets the font to Cambria Math, although scaled Cambria Math gives a summation symbol that’s thicker than you wanted.

```
\documentclass[varwidth, preview]{standalone}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\setmainfont{Cambria}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\newfontface\bigmath{Cambria Math}[Scale=3.0]

\newcommand\bigsum{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\bigmath ∑}}}\limits}

\begin{document}
\(
  \bigsum_k^n \begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&1\end{pmatrix}
\)
\end{document}
```

[image: Cambria Math Sample]

You could vary the `scale=` parameter using the font features commands from `fontspec`, although if you want a specific height, you probably want a `\resizebox` from `graphicx`.

Comment: Note that in your current solution, the large summation symbol is placed on the (text) baseline instead of being centered vertically on the mathline. One could employ a `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}` wrapper in order to get the (vertical) centering right.

Comment: In case my previous comment was too cryptic: Give `\newcommand\bigsum{\mathop{\vcenter{\hbox{\bigmath ∑}}}\limits}` a try. :-)

Comment: Now that you use unicode-math, you could just use the font in the question: Cambria Math

Comment: @Mico Good idea!