# How do I make \sigma bigger?

Tags: math-mode, macros

How can you increase the size of `\sigma`so that it would increase in size like **o** would become an **O** here (like a capital letter)? Preferably this would work when calling `\sigma` straight away without showing the small sign alltogether.

EDIT:
I am looking to make the lower case greek sigma an upper case letter. I am not looking for a sum sign.

I have tried `\renewcommand{\sigma}{\scalebox{2}{$\sigma$}}` but it didn't work. It says sigma already defined.

Comment: Can you show your use-case where you want this to happen?

Comment: Can you also clarify the question? `\sigma` outputs the lowercase greek letter sigma (which is σ). Are you looking for a capital sigma (which is Σ)? Or for a lowercase sigma in a bigger font size? Or simply a similar symbol which would have the size of a capital O?

Comment: Probably this question addresses your query... with very nice answers: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/22773/146828

Comment: Do you really want "sigma" or are you looking for a large summation sign (`\sum`) which grows larger in `\displaystyle` math?

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by “increase in size?” What should the size be?

Comment: I have edited my question with a clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to understand a reason for using the name `\sigma` for the big variant.

Anyway, here it is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\let\originalsigma\sigma
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\sigma}{\mathord{\mathpalette\sigma@\relax}}
\newcommand{\sigma@}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \sbox\z@{$#1O$}%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht\z@}{$\m@th#1\originalsigma$}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
O+\sigma+e^{\sigma t}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
\scalebox{2}{$\sigma$}
```

You can change the value {2} if you need it to be larger.  Please let me know if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Please consider editing you previous answer before adding a new one.

Comment: Thanks Roland, that helps tremendously

Comment: Almost what I am looking for. Although I want \sigma to now produce this new big sigma. I tried `\renewcommand{\sigma}{\scalebox{2}{$\sigma$}}` but it didn't work.

Comment: So if somone has same problem I solved it by adding `\let\ssigma\sigma
\renewcommand{\sigma}{\scalebox{2}{$\ssigma$}}` in preamble.

Comment: Actually, this does not scale well if I try to do something like `e^{\sigma t}`as sigma remain big and does not become smaller as the t.