# Tabular shifts when on a new page

Tags: tables

I'm trying to implement a list of symbols in my document. The first page of the list of symbols looks fine. However, on the second page (and subsequent pages), the tabular is indented for an unknown reason, as can be seen in the figure below (watch the red line). I would like both pages to line up. I'm not able to achieve this.

I don't care whether I have to change the first page for the text to appear as in the second page, or vice-versa, as long as they line up. Does someone know why this behavior happens and how I can achieve what I would like?

The code I used:

```
\chapter*{List of Symbols} \label{list}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\begin{tabular}{cp{1.0\textwidth}}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\begin{tabular}{cp{1.0\textwidth}}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabular}
```

[image: Image of the problem]

Edit: Here, I describe the new problem where the header of the earlier page is displayed in the pages after List of Symbols. This happens when using a tabular spanning over multiple pages. When I manually split the tabular of List of Symbols into multiple pages, the header doesn't appear in the List of Symbols.

```
   \documentclass[english,12pt,a4paper,pdftex,twoside]{report}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsfonts,amssymb,amsbsy}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xltabular}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage{caption} 
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{epstopdf}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=3.5cm,footskip=0.5cm,top=1.8in,bottom=4.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[font={small}]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{tocbibind}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{chngpage}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[figuresright]{rotating}



\setlength\parindent{24pt}


\titleclass{\subsubsubsection}{straight}[\subsection]

\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection]
\renewcommand\thesubsubsubsection{\thesubsubsection.\arabic{subsubsubsection}}
\renewcommand\theparagraph{\thesubsubsubsection.\arabic{paragraph}} % optional; useful if paragraphs are to be numbered

\titleformat{\subsubsubsection}
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubsubsection}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubsubsection}
{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1.5ex plus .2ex}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\paragraph{\@startsection{paragraph}{5}{\z@}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\renewcommand\subparagraph{\@startsection{subparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
  {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
  {-1em}%
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\def\toclevel@subsubsubsection{4}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{5}
\def\toclevel@paragraph{6}
\def\l@subsubsubsection{\@dottedtocline{4}{7em}{4em}}
\def\l@paragraph{\@dottedtocline{5}{10em}{5em}}
\def\l@subparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{4}







\captionsetup[table]{skip = 12 pt}

\newlength{\depthofsumsign}
\setlength{\depthofsumsign}{\depthof{$\sum$}}
\newlength{\totalheightofsumsign}
\newlength{\heightanddepthofargument}

\newcommand{\nsum}[1][1.4]{
    \mathop{
        \raisebox
            {-#1\depthofsumsign+1\depthofsumsign}
            {\scalebox
                {#1}
                {$\displaystyle\sum$}%
            }
    }
}
\newcommand{\resum}[1]{
    \def\s{#1}
    \mathop{
        \mathpalette\resumaux{#1}
    }
}
\newcommand{\resumaux}[2]{
    \sbox0{$#1#2$}
    \sbox1{$#1\sum$}
    \setlength{\heightanddepthofargument}{\wd0+\dp0}
    \setlength{\totalheightofsumsign}{\wd1+\dp1}
    \def\quot{\DivideLengths{\heightanddepthofargument}{\totalheightofsumsign}}
    \nsum[\quot]
}
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/6424/16595
\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\DivideLengths}[2]{
  \strip@pt\dimexpr\number\numexpr\number\dimexpr#1\relax*65536/\number\dimexpr#2\relax\relax sp\relax
}
\makeatother



\newcommand\varpm{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{\hfil$\scriptstyle+$\hfil\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          $\scriptscriptstyle({-})$\cr}%
}}}}
\newcommand\varmp{\mathbin{\vcenter{\hbox{%
  \oalign{\hfil$\scriptstyle-$\hfil\cr
          \noalign{\kern-.3ex}
          $\scriptscriptstyle({+})$\cr}%
}}}}



\setlength{\tabcolsep}{8pt}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyfoot{}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\newcommand{\HRule}{\rule{\linewidth}{0.5mm}}
\hypersetup{pdfpagemode=UseNone, pdfstartview=FitH,
  colorlinks=true,urlcolor=red,linkcolor=black,citecolor=black,
  pdftitle={Default Title, Modify},pdfauthor={Your Name},
  pdfkeywords={Modify keywords}}
\renewcommand*\rmdefault{lmr}
\newcommand{\bb}{\textbf}
\newcommand{\ita}{\textit}
\newcommand{\tx}{\textrm}
\newcommand{\todo}{\textbf{TODO: }}


\newcommand*\xbar[1]{%
   \hbox{%
     \vbox{%
       \hrule height 0.5pt % The actual bar
       \kern0.5ex%         % Distance between bar and symbol
       \hbox{%
         \kern-0.1em%      % Shortening on the left side
         \ensuremath{#1}%
         \kern-0.1em%      % Shortening on the right side
       }%
     }%
   }%
} 

\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0 pt}

\begin{document}

% -----------------------------------------------------

\begin{titlepage}

\selectlanguage{english}

\setlength{\headheight}{3 cm}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[L]{Header1\\ Header1 Header1 Header1\\ Header1 Header1 Header1 Header1 Header1}

\setcounter{page}{0}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\mbox{}\\[2.5cm]

\noindent
Name Lastname\\

\noindent
{\Large \bfseries Title title title \\title}


\mbox{}\\[90 mm]



\noindent
Document type\\
Place, \today \\

\noindent
Supervisor:\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, Supervisor\\
Advisor:\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, Advisor \\




\selectlanguage{english}


\end{titlepage}






% --------------------------------------------------



\clearpage

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{DOCUMENT \\ TYPE}
\fancyhead[L]{Header2 \\ Header2 Header2\\Header2 Header2 Header2 \\Header2}
\selectlanguage{english}

\mbox{}\\[0mm]

\enlargethispage{20mm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l l| }
  \hline
  \bb{Author:} & Name Lastname\\
  \hline
  \bb{Title:} & Title title title\\
  \hline
  \bb{Date:} & \today \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \bb{Pages:}\,\,\, $n+m$\\
  \hline
  \bb{Major:} & Major major major major\\
  \bb{Code:} & 1234\\
  \hline
  \bb{Supervisor:} &  Supervisor\\
  \bb{Advisor:} & Supervisor\\
  \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{
  \parbox{13.2cm}{

\mbox{}\\[0mm]
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem\\

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\
}} \\
  \hline
  \parbox[t][11 mm][t]{2.7cm}{\bb{Keywords:}} & \parbox[t][16mm][t]{10.0cm}{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3} \\
  \hline
  \bb{Language:} & English \\
  \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}


%---------------------------------------------------


\clearpage

\setlength{\headheight}{16pt}
\thispagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead[R]{DOCUMENT\\ TYPE}
\fancyhead[L]{Header2 \\ Header2 Header2\\Header2 Header2 Header2 \\Header2}
\selectlanguage{english}

\mbox{}\\[0mm]

\enlargethispage{20mm}

\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{ |l l| }
  \hline
  \bb{Author:} & Name Lastname\\
  \hline
  \bb{Title:} & Title title title\\
  \hline
  \bb{Date:} & \today \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\, \bb{Pages:}\,\,\, $n+m$\\
  \hline
  \bb{Major:} & Major major major major\\
  \bb{Code:} & 1234\\
  \hline
  \bb{Supervisor:} &  Supervisor\\
  \bb{Advisor:} & Supervisor\\
  \hline

  \multicolumn{2}{|l|}{
  \parbox{13.2cm}{

\mbox{}\\[0mm]
Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum \\

Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
}} \\
  \hline
  \parbox[t][11 mm][t]{2.7cm}{\bb{Keywords:}} & \parbox[t][16mm][t]{10.0cm}{keyword1, keyword2, keyword3} \\
  \hline
  \bb{Language:} & language2\\
  \hline

\end{tabular}
\end{center}

\selectlanguage{english}


%---------------------------------------------------


\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Acknowledgements} \label{ch:ackno}

Thanks for all to be thanked.\mbox{}\\[2.5cm]
\ita{Place, Time time}\\\\\\\\
Author



\vspace*{-38.5mm}

\setlength{\footskip}{40pt}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\nameref{ch:ackno}}


\thispagestyle{plain}

%----------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\chapter*{Abbreviations} \label{abbr}

\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Abbreviations}

\begin{tabular}{cp{0.6\textwidth}}
 ABBR & Abbreviation explanation\\ 
 ABBR & Abbreviation explanation\\
 ABBR & Abbreviation explanation\\
 ABBR & Abbreviation explanation\\
 ABBR & Abbreviation explanation\\
\end{tabular}


%----------------------------------------------------

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}
\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\label{list}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}>{$}r<{$} X @{}}
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\vdots  & other symbols with long explanation other symbols with long explanation other symbols with long explanation            \\
\sigma^2  & standard deviation\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\

\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Supposing that you do not have a two side document, put `\noindent`. Before the second tabular. And, of course, a `tabularx` would make more sense here.

Comment: Thank you. Seriously. I wish I asked sooner instead of wasting over half an hour on the matter.

Comment: Actually, there are still pages where it does not line up. But it's an improvement. @MadyYuvi the @{} does not help either, I will try tabularx next.

Comment: i suggest to use long table, for example `xltabular`. than you no need manually split your table.

Comment: @OppositeSnail Please try the auto breaking package, either "longtable" or "supertabular" to avoid this...

Comment: @Zarko and Red-Line, the xltabular package works, everything is lined up perfectly now. However, this created a new problem. The header from the the previous page before the List of Symbols page is now displayed on the second and subsequent pages after List of Symbols.

Comment: you not provide any information about your document layout. using `tabularx` or `xltabular` should not influence on your settings of page headers or footers. show us complete small document, which gives what you describe (for example add you page layout and used document class to my answer)

Comment: @Zarko I have edited the original question to include the case. As you can see, the header is displayed on the subsequent pages after the first page of List of Symbols. This just got a whole lot more mysterious...

Comment: When i will have some more spare time, i will go through s your document settings,  but at first glance I can only say that it has serious flaws (off-topic to this question).

Comment: Simply adding \fancyhead[R]{} and \fancyhead[L]{} after the new page for the list of symbols helped. Now, the header isn't displayed in the list of symbols anymore. I have no idea why it was displayed there in the first place, since the page style was set to "plain," but hey it works. Thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
\usepackage{tabularx}
...


\chapter*{List of Symbols} \label{list}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabularx}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}cX}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabularx}
```

if you need a page break then use package `xltabular` with the environment of the same name.

Comment: With tabularx, the first and second page line up perfectly, but then the tabular shifts to the left on page 3 and again more to the left on page 4, maybe because of different symbol width?

Comment: Yes, bit you can use _one_ tabular, then you'll get the same column width.

Answer (score 2):

as i mentioned in my comment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{array,xltabular}

\begin{document}
\chapter*{List of Symbols}
\label{list}

\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{}>{$}r<{$} X @{}}
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\vdots  & other symbols with long explanation other symbols with long explanation other symbols with long explanation            \\
\sigma^2  & standard deviation\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\alpha  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\beta   & Explanation of the symbol\\
\gamma  & Explanation of the symbol\\
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

`\noindent` and `@{}` will helps you to achieve your needs:

```
\chapter*{List of Symbols} \label{list}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Symbols}
\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{1.0\textwidth}}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabular}

\clearpage
\thispagestyle{plain}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}cp{1.0\textwidth}}
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 $symbol$ & Explanation of the symbol\\
 ...
\end{tabular}
```

Also, note that there are few packages are available to make the tabular into auto page break mode, e.g., `supertabular` and `longtable` package...